# Reference-error : Console is not defined of java script i cmd

Tags: javascript

[image]

*What should i do ? it is showing reference-error*

Comment: It's called `console`

Comment: I suggest reading the thrown error, Console doesn't exist. Why I downvoted: [reason](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use capital letter :) Object `console` defined with lowercase.

`console.log('hello')`

But I woted to close your question...

Answer (score 0):

You can hit (Ctrl+Shift+i) to inspect the page and see it in the console.

Comment: F12 also works (Function key 12).

Answer (score -1):

**console** is a reserved word and it is case sensitive and it must be written in **lowercase**